# Windows 8 & Ubuntu 12.10 Dual Boot: Windows 8 as default OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) on my laptop with Windows 8 already installed. The installation went successfully and I get to use ubuntu alongside Windows 8. Since I am new quite new to Ubuntu (and I would only use it when devving apps) and majority of my apps and games run in Windows, I would like to set Windows 8 as the default OS. But the thing is, when I start the system, it proceeds first to the Grub Boot Menu (?) with Ubuntu as the default. Can I bypass Grub and proceed to the Windows 8 boot menu since I can choose Ubuntu there?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure grub2 with the command *gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub*
enter that into a terminal. It means: Edit the file /et/default/grub using the application gedit and root rights. There you can configure the following values which are important for you cause:
    GRUB_DEFAULT=   {NUMBER OR "name of entry to boot" OR saved}
-> Where NUMBER and a name correspond to an entry and saved loads the last saved boot option.
    GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT={true OR false}
-> if true saves the last selected entry in the boot menu for use with GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
    GRUB_TIMEOUT={SECONDS}
-> wait for number of SECONDS before booting the selected entry

So I guess you want values like:
    GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/PatitionofWindows)"
    GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
(doesn't hurt and will come handy if you choose to diribute your time more equal on the systems)
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=4
So it will automatically boot into Windows, waiting not too long, but long enough to give you the opportunity to select Linux.
After making and saving the changes you have to issue the command
    *sudo update-grub*
to apply them.